# Does realloc mutate its arguments

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

1. Does `realloc` mutate its first argument?
2. Is mutating the first argument dependent on the implementation?
3. Is there a reason it should not be `const`? As a counter example `memcpy` makes its `src` argument `const`.

ISO C standard, section 7.20.3 Memory management functions, does not specify. The Linux man page for `realloc` does not specify.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int* list = NULL;
  void* mem;
  mem = realloc(list, 64);
  printf("Address of `list`: %p\n", list);
  list = mem;
  printf("Address of `list`: %p\n", list);
  mem = realloc(list, 0);
  printf("Address of `list`: %p\n", list);
  // free(list);  // Double free
  list = mem;
  printf("Address of `list`: %p\n", list);
}
```

When I run the above code on my Debian laptop:

- The first `printf` is `null`.
- The second `printf` has an address.
- The third `printf` has the same address as the second.
- In accordance with the spec, trying to free the address results in a double `free` error.
- The forth `printf` is `null`.

Comment: C is pass-by-value, so the value of the variable list will never be changed by the function call itself.

Comment: @ThomasJager I think he means the memory pointed to by it, since he compares to the source argument to `memcpy()`.

Comment: OT: The conversion specifier `p` is defined for  `void`-pointers only so you need to cast all pointer to `(void*)` t have their values printed, else UB is invoked.

Comment: Consider the argument passed to `realloc` similar with passing it to `free`. Only in a `realloc` *failure* case (which you should check for anyway) is its value *prior* to the call still meaningful.

Comment: I guess the question I wanted to ask was "Would `realloc` be better if its first argument was `void** ptr_to_ptr`?" Then it would be able to change the address based on the situation. I am not sure if I should ask the above question as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function does not change the original pointer because it deals with a copy of the pointer. That is the pointer is not passed by reference.

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    *p = 10;

    printf( "Before p = %p\n", ( void * )p );

    char *q = realloc( p, 2 * sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "After  p = %p\n", ( void * )p );

    free( q );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Before p = 0x5644bcfde260
After  p = 0x5644bcfde260
```

As you see the pointer p was not changed.

However the new pointer `q` can have the same value as pointer p had before the call of realloc.

From the C Standard (7.22.3.5 The realloc function)

> 4 The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (**which
>   may have the same value as a pointer to the old object**), or a null
>   pointer if the new object could not be allocated.

Of course if you will write

```
    p = realloc( p, 2 * sizeof( int ) );
```

instead of

```
    char *q = realloc( p, 2 * sizeof( int ) );
```

then it is evident that in general the new value of pointer `p` can differ from the old value of `p` (though can be the same according to the quote). For example if the function was unable to reallocate memory. In this case a memory leak will occur provided that initial value of the pointer `p` was not equal to `NULL`. Because in this case (when the initial value of the pointer was not equal to `NULL`) the address of the early allocated memory will be lost.

The old memory is not deallocated if a new memory extent can not be
allocated because the function needs to copy the old content to the
new extent of memory.

From the C Standard (7.22.3.5 The realloc function)

> If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is
>   not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Pay attention to that this call

```
mem = realloc(list, 0);
```

does not necessary return NULL.

From the C Standard (7.22.3 Memory management functions)

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the
>   behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Comment: Note that the `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);`  idiom is an incipient memory leak — if the `realloc()` fails and `oldptr` contained the only reference to the memory, it has just been zapped with a null pointer.  The `newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` idiom is correct, as you say (without really explaining why it is correct).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, formally, `realloc` frees the memory pointed to by its first argument after allocating a new object and copying the contents. As such, semantically it's absolutely correct that the pointed-to type not be `const` qualified. In limited cases, the new object's address may be the same as the old object's address, but a correct program largely can't even see this (comparing against the old pointer is undefined behavior), much less depend on it.

Secondly, I think you're confusing the `const`-ness of the argument type and the pointed-to type. `const` on argument types makes no sense whatsoever (and is ignored by the language, except in the implementation of the called function where it makes the local variable receiving the argument constant) since arguments are always **values**, not references to some object in the caller. Of course `realloc` can't change the **value** of the caller's pointer variable you pass to it. However, due to any use of invalid pointers being undefined behavior, your program can (because UB allows anything) exhibit behavior *as if* the caller's copy had been modified. For example, comparing it for equality with the new pointer may give inconsistent results. The `const` on `memcpy`'s `src` makes a pointer-to-`const` type, not a `const` type.

Comment: I don't follow how `const` for the pointed-to space should be considered semantically correct, since one of the things you cannot do with a pointer to `const` is free it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sorry, I meant the status of *not having* `const`. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`realloc()` can free the memory that its argument points to, if it can't reuse the same memory. I think this is considered to be like a mutation (since it effectively destroys it completely).

Semantically, `realloc()` is equivalent to:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
  void *result = malloc(size);
  if (result && ptr) {
    memcpy(result, ptr, min(size, _allocation_size(ptr)));
    free(ptr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

where `_allocation_size()` is some internal function of the C runtime that determines the size of a dynamic memory allocation.

Since the argument to `free()` is not declared `const void *`, neither is the first argument to `realloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Does `realloc` mutate its first argument?".

It certainly doesn't change the value of the pointer in the caller -- no C function can do that.

But does it alter the value of the pointed-to memory?  That's a trickier question.

As far as the programmer is concerned, you hand `realloc` a pointer to M bytes, and it returns you a (possibly different) pointer to N bytes.

If it hands you back the same pointer (meaning that it was able to do the reallocation "in place"), and if N ≥ M, it definitely does not touch the M former bytes.

If it hands you back the same pointer but N < M (that is, if you reallocated the region smaller), you're no longer allowed to access or even ask about the bytes beyond M, so it's particularly hard to say whether they were modified.  (But in fact, they might well have been modified, in the process of marking them unused, and available for future allocation).

Finally, if `realloc` hands you back a different pointer, the M former bytes are "gone" -- again, you're no longer allowed to access them, so it's hard to say if they were modified, but they probably were, because all of them are now available for future allocation.

But in any case: the pointer you hand to `realloc` is a pointer into the heap, and `realloc` definitely alters the heap as it does its work, so yes, I think it's safe to say that `realloc` mutates its first argument, which therefore should not be declared `const`.  (Even in the first case I discussed, where `realloc` "definitely did not touch the M former bytes", it probably did still adjust some nearby data structures, to record the new allocation.)

And, finally, if by "mutate" you mean the sort of thing that C++ programs are allowed to do when member variables are declared `mutable` -- that is, a change happens behind the scenes to some data structure referenced by a pointer that was otherwise qualified `const` -- well, yes, that's not too far off from what `realloc` does.  *If* `realloc's` first argument were `const`, and *if* the modifications `realloc` did perform were to data structures qualified as `mutable`, then I suppose this would work -- but also *if* we were talking about C++.

But of course we're not talking about C++; we're talking about C, which doesn't even have the `mutable` qualifier.

(I'd say `memcpy` isn't a counterexample, because it doesn't do anything that even remotely smells like writing to any data structures associated with its second argument.)

Answer (score 0):

> Does realloc mutate its first argument?

If you mean change the value of the variable passed as parameter the answer is no. The point isn't related to the specific `realloc()` function, but more generally to the way used by the language to handle parameters. C language produce a private copy of each argument, typically on the stack, before to pass them to the function, For this reason each change to them is confined locally and is lost when the function returns and the stack reused. Formally the C language pass almost all types by value (arrays are a well known exception). Anyway I'll come back on the argument below.

> Is mutating the first argument dependent on the implementation?

Of course not. As said above this depends by the language.

> Is there a reason it should not be const? As a counter example memcpy
>   makes its src argument const.

Of course there is a reason.

Forget about `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num )` that has no connection to `void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size)`, lets consider that the management of dynamic memory depends on specific local implementation, but basically all allocation routines are based on memory pools, normally divided in small chunks, from where are derived the memory blocks returned to our programs. We can imagine that when we require to shrink the block the system will remove some chunks giving back a smaller block that incidentally remain at the same address, but if we require an extension maybe the chunks following our block are already assigned we can't proceed.

On an embedded 8 bit micro may happen that the actual memory block cannot be extended, but that another memory area is large enough for the scope, in that case we can copy the former block data to the new one and return it. But in this case we have a different address in memory.

But the `malloc()` must be universal independently from the machine where it is implemented, starting from 8 bits embedded applications to 64bits desktops with GBytes of available memory and virtual memory support. For this reason the standard must provide a definition that could fit all cases.

The second point is how pass the result, pass/fail, of the reallocation, if would have been used a **reference to the memory block pointer** (ie passing `&ptr`), **in case of a failure returning `NULL` the original pointer would have been lost!**. The user, to preserve it, must have done a copy of the pointer before to `realloc()`, but this procedure is unnatural e prone to errors.

For this reason in the standard library the problem is approached from a different side: **the reallocation will formally return always a freshly allocated memory block in which has been copied the former memory block data**. The programmer is required only to check the result before use it (see below code example).

The standard is very clear in the function definition, as already mentioned in other answers, that for sake of completeness I report below. From **ISO/IEC 9899:2017 §7.22.3.5 The realloc function**:

> The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and
>   returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size.
>
> The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the old
>   object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old
>   sizes.
>
> Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have
>   indeterminate values.
>
> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc
>   function for the specified size. Otherwise, if ptr does not match a
>   pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the
>   space has been deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function,
>   the behavior is undefined.
>
> If size is nonzero and memory for the new object is not allocated, the
>   old object is not deallocated.
>
> If size is zero and memory for the new object is not allocated, it is
>   implementation-defined whether the old object is deallocated. If the
>   old object is not deallocated, its value shall be unchanged.
>
> The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may
>   have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer
>   if the new object has not been allocated.

Because you don't know if `realloc()` returns a new object or the former one, or even `NULL` in case of error, you should consider `realloc()` as **always returning a new object**, hence the code:

```
  int* list = NULL;
  void* mem;
  mem = realloc(list, 64);
  printf("Address of `list`: %p\n", list);
```

Is wrong at least for two reasons:

1. Obviously Because if `realloc()` return a new object and frees the
   old memory, the variable `list` contains an invalid pointer. Moreover it could fail returning `NULL`, in that case the former block will still be valid.
2. Because you **can't expect to have `list` changed in any way passing it as a local parameter in a function**. Of course `list` will retain its former value that  is `NULL`.

While passing a null pointer to `realloc()` is standard compliant, because it explicitly says that in this case the behavior will be the same as `malloc()`, passing a **zero size** the behavior is **implementation-defined** implying that the former block will be deallocated by some compilers, but not from some others. The latter means that the behavior can change on compiler basis, on your machine we can deduce that evidently the compiler behavior is to deallocate the block because of the double free error you got and the null pointer returned by `realloc()`. Please note also that in latter case **when passing a zero size to `realloc()`the returned `NULL` could not mean that a failure occurred**, and that the function was successful, **but in case of failure you will not able to correctly understand if there was a failure or not**. This is an ambiguity of the function (or it is so at my knowledge comments are welcome).

The golden rules to follow when using `realloc()` are basically these:

1. Keep in mind that the object returned from function **is always a
   new object** and you have to save it.
2. Because `realloc()` can fail and return a `NULL` pointer, never use
   code as that below, because if it fails we will overwrite the old
   object pointer loosing the possibility to recover data or free the
   former object. Always use a temporary variable to check the return
   value.

Example code:

```
void *p = malloc(SIZE);
/* Wrong approach we overwrite anyway teh pointer */
p = realloc(p, 2*SIZE);

/** Correct approach */
void *pTmp = realloc(p, 2*SIZE);
if (NULL == pTmp)
{
    //Error manage code
}
else
{
    p = pTmp;    //assign value
}
```

Now you may ask why on many machines, having virtual memory management as desktops, smartphones and the like, often happen to have unchanged memory address returned from `realloc()`. Well the point is that, thanks to the virtual memory management, more physical **not contiguous** memory chunks can be added to the virtual memory chain, then the virtual memory descriptors can be manipulated, mapping consequential virtual addresses to each physical chunk in such a way that the user sees a flat contiguous virtual memory space.